# Deleting row from a DataTable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, delete-row

I'm trying to get my delete button from a modal popup to delete a row from my local database which is in Visual Studio.

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'm new to this, so if I'll have to add some data. Please inform me.

This is the Controller:

```
using MusicBox.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MusicBox.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        //Tab Box
        //[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Box()
        {
            return View();
        }


        ////Dobivanje liste unutar gumba
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var viewModel = new MusicViewModel();
            var genres = new List<Genre>();
            var genreList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                genres = db.Genres.ToList();
            }

            foreach (var genre in genres)
            {

                genreList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = genre.Id.ToString(), Text = genre.Type });
            }

            viewModel.Genres = genreList;

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MusicViewModel model)
        {
            //Ovo je validation message
            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    var viewModel = new MusicViewModel();
            //    var genres = new List<Genre>();
            //    var genreList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            //    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            //    {
            //        genres = db.Genres.ToList();
            //    }

            //    foreach (var genre in genres)
            //    {

            //        genreList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = genre.Id.ToString(), Text = genre.Type });
            //    }

            //    viewModel.Genres = genreList;

            //    return View(viewModel);
            //}

            var song = new Song
            {
                GenreId = model.GenreId,
                Performer = model.Performer,
                Title = model.Title,
                Year = model.Year,
                YoutubeLink = model.YoutubeLink
            };




            using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Songs.Add(song);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }



            //ovdje ide dodavanje u bazu
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            var songs = new List<Song>();
            var songList = new List<SongListViewModel>();

            try
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    songs = db.Songs.ToList();

                    foreach (var song in songs)
                    {
                        songList.Add(new SongListViewModel
                        {
                            Performer = song.Performer,
                            Song = song.Title,
                            Genre = song.Genre.Type,
                            Year = song.Year,
                            Link = song.YoutubeLink,
                            Id = song.Id

                        });
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            return View(songList);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View("Create");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
@using System.Activities.Expressions
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MusicBox.Models
@model IEnumerable<SongListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Popis";

}

<h2>Popis pjesama</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Izvođač
        </th>
        <th>
            Pjesma
        </th>

        <th>
            Žanr
        </th>
        <th>
            Godina
        </th>
        <th>
            Youtube Link
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Performer</td>
            <td>@item.Song</td>
            <td>@item.Genre</td>
            <td>@item.Year</td>
            <td><a href="@item.Link" target="_b">Link</a></td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.Id})
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmSongDelete" data-songId="@item.Id">
                    Briši
                </button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>

</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirmSongDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Brisanje pjesme</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Da li sigurno želite izbrisati?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Odustani</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Obriši</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add a delete method in your controller

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Any suggestions how that should look?

Comment: the shell of your call would look just like your other controller actions:
 public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                ........
            }

            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like that:-

> Javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#confirmSongDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
    $("#btnConfirm").attr("id", id);
  });
 })

function DeleteSong(Id) {

$("div[class='Success']").empty();
$("div[class='failure']").empty();
//call action method
$("#confirmSongDelete").modal("hide");

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteSong", "HomeController")",
    data: { id: Id },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null && response == "True") {
            $("#spnSuccessMsg").css("display", "block");
            $("#myModalOk").modal('show');

        } else {
            $("#spnErrorMsg").css("display", "block");
            $("#myModalOk").modal('show');

        }
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }
});
}
 </script>
```

> View

```
@using System.Activities.Expressions
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MusicBox.Models
@model IEnumerable<SongListViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Popis";
}

<h2>Popis pjesama</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead class="thead">
<tr>
    <th>
        Izvođač
    </th>
    <th>
        Pjesma
    </th>

    <th>
        Žanr
    </th>
    <th>
        Godina
    </th>
    <th>
        Youtube Link
    </th>
    <th>

    </th>
    <th>

    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Performer</td>
        <td>@item.Song</td>
        <td>@item.Genre</td>
        <td>@item.Year</td>
        <td><a href="@item.Link" target="_b">Link</a></td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.Id})
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="@item.Id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmSongDelete" data-songId="@item.Id">
                Briši
            </button>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>

</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirmSongDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Brisanje pjesme</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Da li sigurno želite izbrisati?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnConfirm" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="DeleteSong(id);">Odustani</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Obriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> Controller

```
public bool DeleteSong()
    {
        int _deleteResult=0;
        string _songId = Request.QueryString["id"];
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
        Song songsMaster = _context.Songs.Single(m => m.SongId == _songId);
            _context.Songs.Remove(songsMaster);
           _deleteResult= _context.SaveChanges();
        }
       if(_deleteResult>0)
       {
         return true;
       }
       else
       {
        return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: this will not delete the song from the DataBase, it needs to call a controller method

Comment: Now check the controller's delete method.